# iPhone 6s is running 13.0 (17A577), which may not be supported device support by this version of Xcode-10.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode11

I updated my iPhone 6s to iOS 13 and I have Xcode 11.0 and am unable to run my project ton my phone. It gives me a notice of:

Could not locate device support files

and gives me this error:

This iPhone 6s is running iOS 13.0 (17A577), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

[image]

My Xcode version:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You state you have Xcode 11 but you show that you are using Xcode 10.2.1. Use Xcode 11 instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using Xcode 10.2.1 not 11.0.

Obvious one is to update you Xcode.

If it's urgent and you can't update your Xcode right away.
check this link out. https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

After downloading the required OS support.

Go to

> Application -> Xcode -> Right click -> Show Package Contents -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform ->
>   DeviceSupport

and extract it

Comment: you have 13.0 (17A577) device support file ?

Comment: You'll find it in the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue.I download the Developer disk image for iOS 13.0 from here and added support file in Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8).

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.0.zip

Follow Those steps. 1) Unzipped downloaded file

2) Right click on Xcode and click on Show Package Content.

3) Then paste your file on path.

Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platforms -> DeviceSupport

Then Restart Your Xcode. It works for me.

Comment: @rmaddy Xcode 11 Size is 7.67 GB.If we need urgent basis for run project in device    we can folow those steps because it will take time to download 8Gb file also we need to good internet speed.

Comment: How urgent can it be? The iOS device is updated to iOS 13. Use Xcode 11. Keep current. And I'd rather download Xcode 11 from Apple than some mystery files posted on some GitHub page.